# Angular 2 RC2 forms upgrade giving error

Tags: forms, angular

so i am trying to upgrade my forms from RC1 to RC3. I have made changes where i saw fit. i am still however getting the following error:

```
 There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("         <input id="language" type="text" [(ngModel)]="language.strName" formControlName="language" [ERROR ->]#language="ngForm" class="form-control inputSize">
```

Here is my main.ts

```
 import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
 import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
 import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
 import { AppComponent } from './components/app.component';
 import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms';

 enableProdMode()
 bootstrap(AppComponent, [
 HTTP_PROVIDERS,
 disableDeprecatedForms(),
 provideForms()
 ])
 .catch(error=> console.log(error));
```

Here is my component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LanguageMaintenance } from '../Dataclasses/languagemaintenance'
/// <reference path="../typings/bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />
import { NavigationService } from '../services/navigation.service';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { LanguageService } from '../services/language.service';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component'
// import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Control, Validators} from     '@angular/common'
import { NgForm } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'languagemaintenance',
  templateUrl: '../component.html/languagemaintenance.component.html',
  directives: [NavbarComponent, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [LanguageService]
})

export class LanguageMaintenanceComponent {
    public languageUrl: string;
    public http: Http;
    showAddContainer: Boolean = false;
    showEditContainer: Boolean = false;
    editingLanguages: boolean;
    Languages: LanguageMaintenance[];
    // LanguagesMaintenance: String[];
    isLanguageSelected: boolean;
    activeLanguage: LanguageMaintenance;
    saveEditedLanguage: LanguageMaintenance;
    editLanguageSelected: boolean;
    allowLanguageNaviagation: boolean;
    form: FormGroup;
    edittedForm: FormGroup;
    activeDiv: string;
    isLoading: boolean;


    constructor(private _navigationService: NavigationService, private _languageService: LanguageService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.isLanguageSelected = false;
        this.editingLanguages = false;
        this.editLanguageSelected = false;
        this.allowLanguageNaviagation = false;
        this.activeLanguage = new LanguageMaintenance();
        this.saveEditedLanguage = new LanguageMaintenance();
        this.activeDiv = "";
        this.isLoading=true;


       // this.getLanguage();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getLanguages();
        this.isLoading= false;
   }

    getLanguages() {
        this._languageService.getLanguages().subscribe((data) => {
            this.Languages = data;
            this.isLoading= false;
        }, error=>{
            this.isLoading= false;
           console.log(error);
        });


    }

    addLanguage() {

        this.showAddContainer = true;
        this.showEditContainer = false;
        this.activeLanguage = null;
        this.activeDiv = null;

        this.form = new FormGroup({
            language: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            interfaceculture: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            culture: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            description: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        })
    }
```

here is my HTML:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-3" for="language">Language:</label>
                <input id="language" type="text" [(ngModel)]="language.strName" formControlName="language" #language="ngForm" class="form-control inputSize">

            </div>
```

i am not sure if ngForm has changed in RC2, or maybe im understanding it incorrectly. I am very new to angular and this is my first application i have built using Angular. So please feel free to give any advice or critique.

Thanks in advance

for extra reference, here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "translatasaurus",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run watch-css\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss css/main.css",
    "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\""
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "lodash": "^4.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.16",
    "ng2-pagination": "^0.3.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.9.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^0.8.1"
  }
```

}

Comment: You should go: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html and http://plnkr.co/edit/WTu5G9db3p4pKzs0WvW6?p=preview

Comment: One more thing, check which version of router you are using in "package.json"  because current version :"3.0.0-beta.1"

Comment: It seems you're trying to get a handle on the control by doing `#language="ngForm"`. Let's take a step back: why? what are you actually trying to accomplish with the `#language` template variable? There might be a much simpler way

Comment: i am not 100% sure what that #language does, all i know is if i remove it, then my validation doesnt work. so im assuming it links to this:

Comment: this.form = new FormGroup({
            language: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            interfaceculture: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            culture: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            description: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

```
<input ... #controlName="ngForm"...>
```

remove the `#controlName="ngForm"` (in your case `#language="ngForm"`)

This element would then be missing for validators. Change the validator from

```
<div *ngIf="!controlName.untouched>Error!</div>
```

To

```
<div *ngIf="formGroupName.controls.controlName.required>Error!</div>
```

As a side note, after this error, I was facing further issues because I was using angular2-material, which was not compatible with angular2 RC3/ RC4. I had to upgrade the material library from v2.0.0-alpha.5-2 to v2.0.0-alpha.6

Answer (score 0):

The names how form directives are exported were renamed to be more intuitive.

Use instead `#language="ngModel"`

```
<input id="language" type="text" [(ngModel)]="language.strName" formControlName="language" #language="ngModel" class="form-control inputSize">
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc3-2016-06-21

> forms: ngModel should export as ngModel (8e6e90e)

Comment: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("         <input id="language" type="text" [(ngModel)]="language.strName" formControlName="language" [ERROR ->]#language="ngModel" class="form-control inputSize">

Comment: I guess you need to update at least to "RC.3". In RC.2 you might need to add `name="someName"` (with `#language="ngForm")

Comment: i am on RC3 at the moment